# How to display an image or pdf file on new tab in angular js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Below is my page:

[image]

Now when i click on Capture1.png i want to first display that image on new tab without any pop up as shown in my above picture.

Same way when i click on sample.pdf i want to first display pdf on new tab.

This is my html:

```
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
<a target="_blank" href="/Account/FetchFile/{{File_Id}}" ng-click="OpenFile(File_Id)" style="line-height:20px">Capture1.png</a>
<a target="_blank" href="/Account/FetchFile/{{File_Id}}" ng-click="OpenFile(File_Id)" style="line-height:20px">sample.pdf</a>
</div>
```

My Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('MyController', ['ur.file', 'ngResource']);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $resource, $http,$window) {
      var url = "http://localhost:47000/Account/FetchFile/" + fileId;
      $window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

**Server side:**

```
public FileContentResult FetchFile(int id)
        {
            byte[] fileContent = null;
            string fileType = "";
            string fileName = "";

            var file = GetFileByID(id);

            if (file != null)
            {
                fileContent = file.Data;
                fileType = file.ContentType;
                fileName = file.FileName;

                return File(fileContent, fileType, fileName);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

**Now here problem is when i single click on capture1.png then two tabs are open with the pop up(like i shown in the above image) on my page(with option open and save) and 2 tabs get closed and those 2 pop ups appear on my same page as shown in my image**.

Can anybody figure out whats the problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for both image and pdf(opening in new tab):

```
public FileResult GetFile(int id)
byte[] fileContent = null;
string fileType = "";
string fileName = "";

var file = GetFileByID(id);

if (file != null) {
{
fileContent = file.Data;
fileType = file.ContentType;
return File(fileContent, fileType);
}


return null;
}
```

View:

```
<a target="_blank" href="/Account/FetchFile/{{File_Id}}" style="line-height:20px">sample.pdf</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a window first then by using document write you can add any `html` , `<script>` or bind any event to window.

Using object tag to show content would be better to use in your case.

**Code**

```
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $resource, $http, $window) {
  var url = "http://localhost:47000/Account/FetchFile/" + fileId;
  if(fileName.toLowerCase().indexOf('.png'))
    type = 'image/png';
  if(fileName.toLowerCase().indexOf('.pdf'))
      type = 'application/pdf';
  if(fileName.toLowerCase().indexOf('.doc'))        
      type = 'application/msword';
  var newTab = $window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
  newTab.document.write("<object width='400' height='400' data='" + url + "' type='"+ type +"' ></object>");
}
```

[`Type` attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_object_type.asp) value could be change as per your file type, In order to work this you should have flash player installed on your browser.

Hope this could help you, Thanks.

Comment: it is working correctly for image only but not for pdf

Comment: then you need to specifically mention `type` attribute that will contain mimeType

Comment: like how.can you please show me as because i am a newbie in angular js

Comment: @MariaPithia check answer & code, your object tag has one attribute which is type, that takes mimeType of your current data, in case of pdf it must be  `application/pdf`

Comment: @MariaPithia yeah you need to check whether it is doc, image or pdf and as per that set your type and then use that type variable inside our ocde, like we did for url.

Comment: can we discuss this on chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73054/discussion-between-pankajparkar-and-maria-pithia).

Comment: @PankajParkar I use this and work fine, but the browser block the new tab.
How I can fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by blocking new tab?

Comment: When I press the button, it runs `var newTab = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');`  and the browser says 'blocked pop-up' in the ULR bar.

Comment: @Isma90 thats browser setting you need to enable "Allow popup setting"

Comment: @PankajParkar my new tab didn't show content of file, what should I suppose to do ?

Comment: IE9 doesn't support object tag with pdf.. Which browser you are trying?